# How to add applications to Storage Access Framework UI?

Tags: android, storage

Depends on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html
The target is to display content which goes after separator. Please look at screenshot:

[image]

Current code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");

startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and current result:
[image]

Thank you!

**Answer:** Use **Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT** instead of **Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT**

Comment: The thank is for attention and future answers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy. Use `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` instead of `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`